# Magento 2 - Load product, modify attribute and save it back - not working

Tags: magento2, product, catalog, plugin

I try to load a product by SKU, then change the weight to 7777 (for testing) and then save the product.

**app\code\Company\RalSurcharge\etc\di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="company_ralsurcharge"
                type="Company\RalSurcharge\Plugin\RalSurcharge"
                sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

**app\code\Company\RalSurcharge\Plugin\RalSurcharge.php**

(The plugin should be triggerd after adding a new product to the cart)

```
<?php

namespace Company\RalSurcharge\Plugin;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class RalSurcharge
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function afterSave(CartItemRepositoryInterface $subject, AbstractItem $cartItem)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
        $this->logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $this->logger->addWriter($writer);
        $this->logger->info("Hello from afterSave plugin");

        $sku = "ral-6005-surcharge";
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);

        $this->logger->info("current weight");
        $this->logger->info($product->getWeight());    // 123

        $product->setWeight(7777);

        $this->logger->info("after setting weight");
        $this->logger->info($product->getWeight());    // 7777

        $product->save();
        ...
```

**Output:**

```
Hello from afterSave plugin
current weight
123
after setting weight
7777
```

First it looks like it worked and that the setting was changed to 7777,
but if I trigger the code again, then I still get the same output:

**Output:**

```
Hello from afterSave plugin
current weight
123
after setting weight
7777
```

Instead of

```
Hello from afterSave plugin
current weight
7777
after setting weight
7777
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer [here](https://www.czettner.com/2018/10/12/update-products-programmatically-faster.html).

You have to use the ResourceModel

```
<?php

namespace Company\RalSurcharge\Plugin;

use \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;

class RalSurcharge
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $productRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $productResourceModel;

    public function __construct(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        ResourceModel $productResourceModel
    ) {
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->productResourceModel = $productResourceModel;
    }

    public function afterSave(CartItemRepositoryInterface $subject, AbstractItem $cartItem)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/zend_debug.log');
        $this->logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $this->logger->addWriter($writer);
        $this->logger->info("Hello from afterSave plugin");

        $sku = "ral-6005-surcharge";
        $product = $this->productRepository->get($sku);

        $this->logger->info("current weight");
        $this->logger->info($product->getWeight());    // 123

        $product->setWeight(7777);

        $this->logger->info("after setting weight");
        $this->logger->info($product->getWeight());    // 7777

        $this->productResourceModel->saveAttribute($product, "weight");

        ...
```